# Check if private key is malformed

Tags: ssh

I've been moving a private key manually via the terminal and I'm getting an error. I suspect this error is caused by malformed key.

Is there a way to check if a key string is correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question was already answered [here](https://serverfault.com/a/426429/355817) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274622/5088142)

You can execute the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen -y -e -f <private key>
```

Takes a private key an prints the corresponding public key which can be directly compared to your available public keys. (Hint: beware of comments or key-options)

You can use also:

```
openssl dsa -in <private key> -modulus -noout
```

Display the public keys corresponding to a private key, then compare them.

Comment: @KarlMorrison - did I answer your question?